# strust 2 (jquery plugin) show action exceptions as ajax error

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

Can you tell me how can I get the action exceptions , convert and send them as json errors. I am using the strust2 jquery plugin to validate my forms with ajax. The framework will do it automatically by defining the `sj:submit validate=true` and annotating the actions

```
<s:form action="login">
    <s:textfield name="username" />
    <s:textfield name="password" />
    <sj:submit button="true" validate="true" />
</s:form>
```

The action is:

```
    @Validations(requiredStrings = 
     { @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName = "username", key = "validate.required"), 
       @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName = "password", key = "validate.required")}

    public String confirm(){

    service.canLogin(username,password)    


}
```

The `canLogin` may throws exception, eg. when it can not connect to database or shomething.

To serialze the excption I added below:

```
<global-results>
<result name="error.core" type="json">
        <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
        <param name="includeProperties">
              actionErrors\[\d+\], fieldErrors\..+$,actionMessages\[\d+\]</param>
            </result>
</global-results>
```

When I submit the form with invalid data, the form validates correctly. When an exception rasies the page is not serializing json results.

During debug I found that two json calls are made to server, one with:

1. All form data's
2. struts.enableJSONValidation
3. struts.validateOnly

and one only with all for data's

Comment: What is your action configuration. Could you describe in detail the process of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer! Hope be useful for others...

The goal is catch bussiness exception and show them to user as ajax validation exceptions.

Set the target of the `sj:form` to some dummy div analyze, your data and do what you want.

The jsp will be

```
    <sj:submit button="true" targets="dummy"
        validateFunction="formValidator" onBeforeTopics="removeErrors"
        onSuccessTopics="formServerErrorAnalyze" validate="true"
        key="form.btn.transfer"  />
```

The js will be

```
$.subscribe("formServerErrorAnalyze", function(event, data) {
        var data = event.originalEvent.data;
            if (data=='Some Exception from server')
             {
                //Do some thing to show error.
                //eg: $("#formerrors").html(data)
             }

        else {
            // Put the content of dummy node into content and remove dummy html
            var working = $("#dummy").contents();
            var ref = $("#content").contents();
            $("#dummy").append(ref);
            $("#content").append(working);
        }
        $("#dummy").html('');
    });
```

There is a bug in struts-jquery. If you do not set the target of `sj:submit` the tag `onSuccessTopics` will not fire! If this is solved, you do not need the dummy div any more.